# JSON Parsing Error - Unable to update core database values

Tags: java, json, angularjs, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS over AngularJS, but I have hit a stumbling block due to json parsing errors.

Using jsonlint I can see the issues, but as I cannot update the underlying database values which are causing the issue to correct the characters (corporate data warehouse)...I am now in trouble as I can't return any data at all into the application because just a small handful of records have non compliant characters in them.

What is the general approach for dealing with these kind of issues?  Is it to search and replace for non ascii- characters at the java end in the setter?

Update:

Error from Chrome:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ub (http://localhost:8080/misf-web/lib/angular/angular.min.js:13:122)
    at e.defaults.transformResponse (http://localhost:8080/misf-web/lib/angular/angular.min.js:98:83)
    at http://localhost:8080/misf-web/lib/angular/angular.min.js:97:347
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at n (http://localhost:8080/misf-web/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:470)
    at Yb (http://localhost:8080/misf-web/lib/angular/angular.min.js:97:329)
    at c (http://localhost:8080/misf-web/lib/angular/angular.min.js:99:14)
    at i (http://localhost:8080/misf-web/lib/angular/angular.min.js:79:437)
    at http://localhost:8080/misf-web/lib/angular/angular.min.js:80:485 angular.min.js:63
(anonymous function)
```

Sample JSON output - just one example which is causing me issues...it is not always "umlauts"...

> {
>       "approvedPriority": "Approved",
>       "disease": "primary Sj�grens Syndrome",
>       "diseaseArea": "Inflammation",
>       "projectType": "NME",
>       "therapyArea": "RI" 
>   }

In the database this disease appears as "primary Sjögren’s Syndrome"

jsonlint reports:

> Parse error on line 3: ...ed",    "disease": "primary Sj�grens S
>   ----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

It is not always "umlauts" causing me issues, sometimes it is a non printable charachter it seems, and one odd error I hunted down due to what appears to be a slightly wider hyphen than normal.

Update:

As far as I am aware I am requesting UTF-8 via JAX-RS.

```
@GET
    @Path("/projects")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
    public List<Project> getAllProjects() {
        logger.debug("GET: list all projects");
        return projectService.getAllProjects();
    }
```

I am developing on Tomcat 7 on Windows using Eclipse.

Comment: Please, show us the errors and the JSON.

Comment: updated main message...sensitive data, so only provided salient points impacting json failure (one example anyway).  Thanks

Comment: What charset are you using? I recommend you use UTF-8.

Comment: Either that JSON parser is defective, or the JSON text is somehow getting garbled (though I don't know how) before it gets to the parser.  But make sure that your JSON is always handled as Unicode, not some other code set, and is presented to the parser either as a Java String or as an array of UTF8-encoded bytes.

Comment: To expand:  A JSON parser should recognize as a legitimate string any character combination between the starting and ending `"` characters, so long as the characters are legit Unicode characters.

Comment: (And note that diagnostic dumps will not always render extended characters correctly.)

Comment: (You might want to do a hex/numeric dump of the JSON string, so you can determine what characters are actually there.)

Comment: Hi I am not sure that the AngularJS json parser would be defective? Or Jax-RS.  I have updated the main message, I am annotating the JAX-RS class to produce UTF-8.  I am using tomcat 7 on windows, via Eclipse.

Comment: I have set up in Eclipse the argument for my Tomcat run configuration:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8  - still doesn't work.  I did this based on this link http://blog.jamesbayley.com/2013/09/09/tomcat-7-on-windows-is-not-utf-8-by-default/

Comment: You need to dump the numeric values of the characters at the point they are handed over to the JSON parser (after any character set translations).  If the chars there are legit Unicode then the parser's defective.

Comment: It is not the parser...the output is scrambled when I use a pure rest client in chrome to test the raw response.  Even though the header in the rest response states charset=utf-8.  Its something on the java side, whether its tomcat or Jax-rs I am not sure.  So its garbled regardless of it hitting the angular parser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59527/discussion-between-user1754307-and-hot-licks).

Comment: charachter according to java is hex "f6" which equates to a valid unicode character.

Comment: How are you printing that f6? Are you taking it from a String charAt, or a byte[] array?

Comment: Unicode F6 is indeed small `o` with diaeresis.  Would be legit as a Char in a String.  Would not be legit as an 8-bit char in a byte[] array -- should be the pair c3 b6 instead.

Comment: using this technique for converting to hex values  http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/05/convert-hex-to-ascii-and-ascii-to-hex/

Comment: Still cant get this to work.  Have uploaded war file to linux tomcat in case it is related to Tomcat on windows, but still an issue.  Is this related to the NVARCHAR data type using MS SQL Server somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems @PRODUCES and adding charset=utf-8 doesn't work.

In the end I created a filter which added charset=utf=8 to the response header before it was sent and registered it as a provider to jersey through the application config class.

Now it works and data is being returned perfectly.

Why @PRODUCES doesn't work is a mystery.

package com.mycompany.misf.filters;

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


public class HeaderResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
            MediaType type = response.getMediaType();
            if (type != null) {
                String contentType = type.toString();
                if (!contentType.contains("charset")) {
                    contentType = contentType + ";charset=utf-8";
                    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", contentType);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Register the filter as a provider.

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public RestApplication() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> c = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        c.add(PersonsRestService.class);
        c.add(ProjectsRestService.class);

        //add this
        c.add(HeaderResponseFilter.class);


        Set<Class<?>> classes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(c);
        registerClasses(classes);

        property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    }
}
```